# Problem with SSO URL on smartphone in MES use

Tags: single-sign-on, sapui5

We are having a problem with our SSO URL, especially a problem on smartphone in MES use case where the users do not know their SAP password and we have to propose them the regular windows credentials to connect to SAP.

With our simple SSO URL, it work perfectly. Now MES always add a parameter to the URL to transmit information like a Guid. So when I start the same URL with the parameter then the phone redirects directly to our Non-SSO URL.

This is a big problem, because the workers using MES have no idea about their SAP credentials, and they are instructed to enter their windows credentials.

Could some one please guide me on this.

Comment: I’m trying to understand the issue.
The abbreviation MES stands for Manufacturing-Execution-System?

Comment: where is ui5 involved? is MES an SAP standard app or external url you are opening from an ui5 app?